# bzr remove to delete a file with branch having uncommited changes

Tags: bazaar

I have to delete a versioned file my bzr  repository using bzr remove command.

> > > bzr remove file_name

it deletes the versioned file (from the file system)

I cannot use bzr commit , (as the file has been deleted from the repository)

> > > bzr commit

Commits all the  changed file to the repository.

How do i deleted file alone, even though i have uncommited changes in my branch?

commits all the unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are asking. With Bazaar version 1.6.1, I can do what you seem to want to do.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/wd; cd /tmp/wd
$ bzr init
$ touch foo bar
$ bzr add foo bar
added foo
added bar
$ bzr commit -m Initial
Committing to: /tmp/wd/
added foo
added bar
Committed revision 1.
$ echo 123 > bar
$ bzr rm foo 
deleted foo
```

Now, I've removed `foo` from the tree, but `bar` has uncommitted changes. To commit the deletion, I use:

```
$ bzr commit foo -m "Deleting foo"
Committing to: /tmp/wd/
deleted foo
Committed revision 2.
```

Revision 2 doesn't see the change to `bar`

```
$ bzr diff -r1..2
=== removed file 'foo'
```

but the working tree does

```
$ bzr diff
=== modified file 'bar'
--- bar 2009-01-20 06:06:37 +0000
+++ bar 2009-01-20 06:07:07 +0000
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+123
```

Am I misunderstanding the questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bzr commit <target>` to only commit certain changes in your branch. For example, if the file you removed is called `testfile.php`, `bzr commit testfile.php` will commit only the removal of that file.

This also works on directories:

`bzr commit testdirectory`